# Add labels in r

Tags: r

Can you help me on putting labels (data) on the following graph?

Here is my code

```
plot(fit.con, xlim = c(0,.5), ylim = c(.5,1), main = "Comparison of multiple and single sequence")
lines(sroc(fit.con2), lty = 2)
ROCellipse(fit.con2, lty = 2, pch = 2, add = TRUE)
points(fpr(con), sens(con), cex = .5)
points(fpr(con2), sens(con2), pch = 2, cex = 0.5)
legend("bottomright", c("multiple", "single"), pch = 1:2, lty = 1:2)
```

[image: ter image description here]

I created the graph based on the code. The variable called con$authors contains the name of total five studies. I know that text function might work, but just don't know where to put in the code.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `text`along these lines: `text(position on x-axis, position on y-axis, what text to plot, ...)`. If you can provide some reproducible data, we'll be able to help you more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I manually find each point's coordination using locator(1) function and add each label by using text(x coordination, y coordination, "name").